# using inner class in Java

Tags: java

I am now working on a recommending system. I designed a class Recommend like:

```
class Recommend{
    Path path; //recommended path, self-defined class. This is the problem!
    //some parameters and Models        
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> Model1;
    //...other pram and models

    //methods
    public void getPath();
    public double score(int place);//
}
```

Here is my problem: I construct a instance of Recommend, loading the models. Then I search a path by calling getPath method of that instance. My path is time sensitive which contains a list of locations along with the right time:

```
class Path{
    List<Integer> path;
    List<Integer> times;
    double socre;

    public void add(int place, double time);
}
```

I want to call add(int, double) to add a place and the correspond time to a path, meanwhile update the score of the new path. So **here I want to call score(int), which is a method of Recommend**

How should I design Path, should it be an inner class of Recommend?

**UPDATE**

```
getPath(int place, double startTime);
//try greedy searching to find a time sensitive path that scored highest, 
//go through all possible places and scored them.

socre(int place, double time);
//In fact there are multiple score methods correspond to different models,
//**and notice here I modify the param to int place from Path path**
//This function evaluates the score of current place and time(used in greedy searching)

add(int place, double time);
//add a new place and time(which is proved by greedy searching to be the best)
//I want this update the score of place itself...okay maybe I should place this function in Recommend
```

Comment: Why don't you make the `score` method belong to the `Path` class

Comment: It would be fit for [programmers.stackexchange.com/](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RC. @rai.skumar I've considered this practice. The code above is a demo, in practice the there is whole bunch of models that need to be initialized in Recommend. And Recommend is kind of stable, which may have only one instance in runtime. In contrast, Path is NOT, so if I place `score` in that class(which is strongly depend on those models), whenever I want to instantiate a new instance of Path, I need to initialize the models, that's inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your "getPath()" method is part of the problem; it "doesn't do anything".  Your "Recommend" class appears to be designed to score the path--and the path doesn't appear to be actually exposed outside of Recommend.  What you might consider doing is expose a new method on Recommand, which is "add(int place, double time)", and have that method update the path, and then call a PRIVATE "scorePath()" method. Then path should be an inner class, as it's only function is to hold the data structure.

You can clarify what you're trying to do by writing down the purpose of each class within a JavaDoc.  Each class should have 1 clear purpose. If, for e.g., once you've done that you discover that "Path" doesn't need to appear outside of "Recommend", then you can make it a private member.

Comment: thanks for your relevant advice, I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Weather you use **Inner Class** or **Composition**(as you have done), you can achieve your goal. I think things are more complicated because you are not following `Separation of Concern` principle.

Think on lines of why do you need **getPath()** and **score()** methods inside **Recommend** class. Like **add()** method, your **getPath()** should also be part of **Path** class.

Comment: I explained this in the comment to RC. please refer to that.